# How to change the textcolor of textView in navigation drawer using state drawable

Tags: android

I want this when have a click in the listview:
[image]

but, I need this:
[image]

I trying use a state drawable to change de color of listview

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red_color" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

It is this ok. But the stateDrawble to change color of text view don't work

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:color="#000000" /></selector>
```

how to make to change the color of textview?

Comment: you can set a selector as textColor attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/drawer_color" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/drawer_color" />
```

Then set textColor property of Textview an set clickable=true

```
 <TextView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/registration"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```